# CefSharp WPF does not load contents after upgrade

Tags: cefsharp

I recently upgraded the cefsharp wpf from 69.0.0 to 71.0.0 and  creating the browser using the managedcefbrowseradapter has changed and when using IWindowInfo as parameter the browser is not getting rendered . Earlier when just passing the window handle was working properly. Any breaking changes here which i have to adapt?

Working one - 69.0.0

_managedCefBrowserAdapter.CreateBrowser(BrowserSettings, RequestContext,_window.Handle, address);

not working - 71.0.0

IWindowInfo window = new WindowInfo();
 window.WindowHandle = _window.Handle;
_managedCefBrowserAdapter.CreateBrowser(window, BrowserSettings, RequestContext, address);

### Edited to add more details.

The CEF browser is hosted within WPF control which is inherited from System.Windows.Controls. The project uses cefsharp.wfp 
The WPF control handle is stored in ControlHandle property . 
Cef is initialized using the CefSettings from cesharp.wpf namespace.

```
 CefSettings settings = new CefSettings
                {
                    CachePath="xxxxx",
                    PersistSessionCookies = true,
                    LogSeverity = LogSeverity.Default,
                    LogFile = Path.Combine(logsFolder, "xxxxx.log"),
                    Locale = "en-US",
                    ResourcesDirPath = "xxxxxx"
                }
             Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

We have a custom class CefBrowser which implements cefsharp.internals.IWebBrowserInternal and uses ManagedCefBrowserAdapter to create the cefBrowser.

```
NativeWindow window = new NativeWindow()
window.CreateHandle(new CreateParams());
IWindowInfo infowindow = new WindowInfo();
infowindow.WindowHandle = window.Handle;
```

A native window would be created and that would be set as the window handle.
ManagedCefBrowserAdapter createbrowser would be created with the window handle.

```
 _managedCefBrowserAdapter.CreateBrowser(infowindow , BrowserSettings, RequestContext, address);
```

One the browser is created , In OnAfterBrowserCreated method, SetParent API would be called to set the parent of cefsharp browser host to the WPF control .

```
void IWebBrowserInternal.OnAfterBrowserCreated(IBrowser browser)
        {
            _browser = browser;
                        SetParent(browser.GetHost().GetWindowHandle(), ControlHandle);          

            ResizeBrowser(Size); //WPF control size 

            OnBrowserCreated(new EventArgs());
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private Members

        private void OnBrowserCreated(EventArgs args)
        {
            EventHandler<EventArgs> handler = BrowserCreated;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, args);
            }
        }
```

This was working till 69.0.0 version with the call  _managedCefBrowserAdapter.CreateBrowser(BrowserSettings, RequestContext,window.Handle, address).
With 71.0.0 it is broken with the call using IWindowInfo and no pages are rendered.

Comment: You should review the WPF source code.

Comment: Also there are no signs that you are actually using the `WPF` project, please edit your post to clarify what you are doing.

Comment: @amaitland , what more properties to be initialized for WindowInfo. We have a custom class CefBrowser that implements IWebBrowserInternal and have a IBrowserAdapter instance  and using that instance  we create the browser. _managedCefBrowserAdapter.CreateBrowser.  can you let me know what more details are required?

Comment: The information you have provided is conflicting, you say WPF yet CreateBrowser was only used in the WinForms versions previously, WPF used CreateOffscreenBrowser. So I cannot answer this. There are only three places that CreateBrowser is actually called,  so look at the source and find the relevant case.

Comment: @amaitland I have provided more details , please advise

Comment: Please be patient, posting multiple times is entirely unnecessary. Your code doesn't make sense to me, all I can say for sure is that previously `CreateBrowser` was only called in the `WinForms` version, so that's the place to start looking for an example that's relevant now.

Comment: earlier  duplicate comment deleted. From the microsoft nuget update , only cefsharp.dll, cefsharp.core.dll, cefsharp.wpf.dll are used and we don't use cefsharp.winforms.dll
ManagedCefBrowserAdapter createbrowser is in CefSharp namespace.

Comment: Please read over my comments in more detail. You need an example of how to use CreateBrowser then look at the source on GitHub to find one.